# Why doesn't dropping this SpawnHandle cancel its future?

Tags: rust, future, rust-tokio

Here is an example program:

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate tokio_core;

use futures::{Async, Future, Stream};
use tokio_core::reactor::Core;
use tokio_core::net::TcpListener;

fn main() {
    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();

    futures::sync::oneshot::spawn(
        TcpListener::bind(&"127.0.0.1:5000".parse().unwrap(), &core.handle())
            .unwrap()
            .incoming()
            .for_each(|_| {
                println!("connection received");
                Ok(())
            }),
        &core,
    );

    let ft = futures::future::poll_fn::<(), (), _>(|| {
        std::thread::sleep_ms(50);
        Ok(Async::NotReady)
    });

    core.run(ft);
}
```

As you can see, I call `oneshot::spawn` and then immediately drop its return value, which should theoretically cancel the future contained inside. However, when I run this program and then make a connection to `127.0.0.1:5000`, it still prints "connection received." Why does it do this? I expected it to not print anything and drop the `TcpListener`, unbinding from the port.

Comment: Could it be that the future has registered itself with the `Core`, thus you've only dropped one of multiple shared owners?

Comment: I'm assuming this is related to my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48359296/why-doesnt-dropping-this-spawnhandle-cancel-its-future - sorry for not having tested it.  I'll look into it.

Comment: It's an inverted logic [bug in `futures`](https://github.com/alexcrichton/futures-rs/issues/669).  If you call `forget()` on the `SpawnHandle` it should actually drop it, which is the opposite of what the doc says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a (now fixed) [bug in the `futures` crate](https://github.com/alexcrichton/futures-rs/issues/669); version `0.1.18` should include the fix.

It used inverted values for `keep_running: bool` in `SpawnHandle`/`Executor`.